# HTML Editor in Orchard 1.4

Tags: orchardcms

I had a look around on SO to see if someone has asked this question before or not, but couldn't find any posts. My apologizes, if this is a duplicate question.

In Orchard 1.3, there is a module for HTML field that one can use...but there is nothing in Orchard 1.4. How do I go about creating a content type with multiple HTML fields? ( Just adding it in UI and not coding).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the opposite. There wasn't one out of the box in 1.3, and you had to download one from the gallery, whereas it's built-in 1.4.

Comment: Just downloaded and tested. Can change the Display option to Html for Textbox field. Thanks!